# Unable to install ubuntu, computer restarts before reaching installation

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dvd, asus

I’m on a ASUS GL752VW laptop trying to dual-boot ubuntu 16.04 with my windows 10 installed in LEGACY bios with a burned DVD.
When I get to the (legacy) installer whatever the option I choose in the installer my computer just goes black screen for several seconds then restart.
PS: I tried the acpi=off and it didn't solve my problem neither did my attempt to make another DVD.

Comment: You could also try nomodeset.

Comment: I tried the nomodrset but it didn’t change a bit what happens after I click install ubuntu..

Comment: If you're seeing the ubuntu loading icon, you can press `esc` and see the systemd messages. This could give us an actual error to help you with. Otherwise we don't have much to go on here...

Comment: try text mode installation

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be in NVIDIA. after the GRUB menu appears, select `Try Ubuntu` and press `E` . add `nouveau.modeset=0` in boot parameters (after word `splash`). If it will not help, and you install 16.04.3, trying install 16.04.2 - in 16.04.3 problem with kernel and NVIDIA. 
After installation, updated the system (and rebooted the PC)
After install Ubuntu remove (`purge`) driver `nouveau` and install prorietary driver NVIDIA. 
To do this, restart the PC and select Ubuntu in GRUB, press `E`.
Add `nouveau.modeset = 0` after quite splash and hit `F10`. 
When booted, exit the graphical mode (Ctrl + Alt + F1), enter your login and password, and uninstall the driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Then install a proprietary driver from the NVIDIA site (in my opinion, now for the GTX960M was nvidia-387).

To do this, you need to restart the PC and add nouveau.modeset = 0 after quite splash, press F10.

Exit the graphical mode (Ctrl + Alt + F1) and use the following commands to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: graphics-drivers / ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-387
sudo reboot
```

something like this

reading https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?81702-Linux-installation-in-ASUS-ROG-GL552VW-DH71

read more https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: FYI - He's failing in the install, there is no grub... Also no mention of NVIDIA anywhere in the question...

Comment: To sam: mentioned ASUS GL752VW laptop. reading https://www.asus.com/us/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-GL752VW/specifications/. You should not choose "install", but "try"